# How to add flow table on each two switches? (mininet)

Tags: sdn, mininet, openflow

I set topology as can seen in the image below. I want to add different flow-tables to each switch. But if I type

```
dpctl add-flow in_port=1,nw_dst=10.0.0.2,actions=output:3
```

the flow table is added to both s1 and s2!

How can I add a different flow-table to each switch?

[image: screen capture]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this with dpctl command, you have to use "sh ovs-ofctl" command.

Also mininet answered a question related with dpctl in [this link](https://github.com/mininet/mininet/wiki/FAQ#dpctl)

Here is what i did:

```
yavuz@ubuntu:~$ sudo mn --topo linear,2,1  --switch ovsk --controller=remote
*** Creating network
*** Adding controller
Connecting to remote controller at 127.0.0.1:6653
*** Adding hosts:
h1 h2
*** Adding switches:
s1 s2
*** Adding links:
(h1, s1) (h2, s2) (s2, s1)
*** Configuring hosts
h1 h2
*** Starting controller
c0
*** Starting 2 switches
s1 s2 ...
*** Starting CLI:
```

Lets dump flows:

```
mininet> dpctl dump-flows
*** s1 ------------------------------------------------------------------------
NXST_FLOW reply (xid=0x4):
 cookie=0x0, duration=10.979s, table=0, n_packets=21, n_bytes=1674, idle_age=1, priority=0 actions=CONTROLLER:65535
*** s2 ------------------------------------------------------------------------
NXST_FLOW reply (xid=0x4):
 cookie=0x0, duration=10.974s, table=0, n_packets=21, n_bytes=1674, idle_age=1, priority=0 actions=CONTROLLER:65535
```

Add a flow to s1:

```
mininet> sh ovs-ofctl add-flow s1 in_port=5,nw_dst=10.0.0.5,actions=output:5
2017-08-03T16:06:41Z|00001|ofp_util|INFO|normalization changed ofp_match, details:
2017-08-03T16:06:41Z|00002|ofp_util|INFO| pre: in_port=5,nw_dst=10.0.0.5
2017-08-03T16:06:41Z|00003|ofp_util|INFO|post: in_port=5
```

Now, as seen in flow dump, flows for each switch are different:

```
mininet> dpctl dump-flows
*** s1 ------------------------------------------------------------------------
NXST_FLOW reply (xid=0x4):
 cookie=0x0, duration=2.644s, table=0, n_packets=0, n_bytes=0, idle_age=2, in_port=5 actions=output:5
 cookie=0x0, duration=20.971s, table=0, n_packets=21, n_bytes=1674, idle_age=11, priority=0 actions=CONTROLLER:65535
*** s2 ------------------------------------------------------------------------
NXST_FLOW reply (xid=0x4):
 cookie=0x0, duration=20.965s, table=0, n_packets=21, n_bytes=1674, idle_age=11, priority=0 actions=CONTROLLER:65535
mininet>
```

Comment: Thank you!! Now I can do it

Comment: I don't know how to study about SDN.. Could you tell me some tips?

Comment: Mininet with RYU is a very good starting point. You've started at the right place. I can also advice https://www.udemy.com/sdn-openflow-nfv-introduction course to understand basic concepts. If you have questions for certain issues about SDN i'd like to help if i can.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. How could send data using new connection (flow)? Is `s1 ping 10.0.0.5`?

Answer (score -1):

If already a link is created how do we set the priority  of the link from xterm hosts

Comment: Would you elaborate "xterm hosts"?